# How version is returned when we type software -version from command prompt

Tags: java, classpath, apache-fop

I wanted to know how a version of the software is returned when we give sofware_name -version is typed from command prompt.

Ex: I have downloaded Apache FOP 2.6 zip file and i went to the extracted fop path.
From there i have entered fop -version. It returned FOP 2.6.

So, i got curious to know how this version is returned.
Note: I have not set the path, still i got the version.

Thanks for explanation in advance.

Regards,

Raj

Comment: Because the application is programmed to print that information when passed that command line option.

Comment: The software implements that on its own. `--version` is just a regular command line switch like any other. If the developers of FOP were nefarious nothing would stop them from instead deleting all your files when you run `fop --version` :)

Comment: You could have a look at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12 describing the argument syntax of the standard utilities. It details the command line argument syntax convention that, to a certain extend, are followed by most programs.